# Merge two json using php

Tags: php, json

I have simple JSON like

```
[{
        "id": "77",
        "agent_id": "20",
        "raised_by": "C",
        "from_date": "2016-11-09",
        "to_date": "2016-11-10",
        "ConsultantInfo": {
            "user_id": "3045",
            "inquiry_id": "77"
        },
        "otherInfo": {
            "a": "test",
            "b": "testing"
        }
}]
```

When I click on save button at that time I need to merge some data existing json data like below, every time new data will come when I click on save button, so I have to store all that data into json file as an array.

```
[{
        "ConsultantInfo": {
            "user_id": "1",
            "inquiry_id": "2"
        },
        "otherInfo": {
            "a": "abc",
            "b": "xyz"
        }
}]
```

so final result should be like this:

```
[{
    "id": "77",
    "agent_id": "20",
    "raised_by": "C",
    "from_date": "2016-11-09",
    "to_date": "2016-11-10",
    "ConsultantInfo": [
        {
        "user_id": "3045",
        "inquiry_id": "77"
        },
        {
        "user_id": "2",
        "inquiry_id": "71"
        } 
    ],
    "otherInfo": [
      {
        "a": "test",
        "b": "testing"
      },
      {
        "a": "kk",
        "b": "dd"
      } 
    ]
}]
```

Mycode:

```
<?php

    $state_current_arr = '{ "id": "77", "agent_id": "20", "raised_by": "C", "from_date": "2016-11-09", "to_date": "2016-11-10" }';
    if(isset($_POST['savebtn'])) //save button
    {
    $jsonData = array();
    $jsonData['ConsultantInfo'] = array("user_id"=>"3045","inquiry_id"=>"77");
    $jsonData['otherInfo'] = array("a"=>"test","b"=>"testing");

    $tempArray = json_decode($state_current_arr,true);
    $tempArray = array_merge($tempArray, $jsonData);
    $jsonData_merged = json_encode($tempArray);

    echo $jsonData_merged;
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `array_merge_recursive` but you need to modify `ConsultantInfo` and `otherInfo` to multidimensional array

try this:

```
$state_current_arr = '{ "id": "77", "agent_id": "20", "raised_by": "C", "from_date": "2016-11-09", "to_date": "2016-11-10" }';

$jsonData = array();
$jsonData['ConsultantInfo'][] = array("user_id"=>"3045","inquiry_id"=>"77");
$jsonData['otherInfo'][]      = array("a"=>"test","b"=>"testing");

$tempArray = json_decode($state_current_arr,true);

$dataRequired = array();
$dataRequired['ConsultantInfo'][] = array("user_id"=>"1","inquiry_id"=>"2");
$dataRequired['otherInfo'][]      = array("a"=>"abc","b"=>"xyz");

$jsonData_merged = array_merge_recursive($tempArray,$jsonData,$dataRequired);

var_dump($jsonData_merged);
```

Comment: This is far from a good solution. A great solution would be something that works regardless of the JSON structure, works with arbitrary number of json arrays and so on.

Comment: you need a json string then just use

Comment: ups, entered to soon, i mean use `json_encode`
echo json_encode($jsonData_merged);

Comment: Ahmad, my point is, the algorithm is weak and dirty - it's not a general solution that will work for joining two or more JSON arrays of any sort. In other words, it will only work in this example.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac ah, yes thanks you, it needs more research